Azure Data Factory find JSON object by specific string/value then select a different value
I have a Legacy API (with no Dev support) I am pulling data out of. Below is the output of activity().outputs.body.data
                {
                "column_id": 1,
                "type": "text",
                "varname": "foo_id",
                "label": "Foo ID",
                "value": "1234",
                "is_core": "yes",
                "orig_label": "Foo ID"
            },
            {
                "column_id": 23,
                "type": "text",
                "varname": "Foo_name",
                "label": "Foo name",
                "value": "blah blah",
                "is_core": "yes",
                "orig_label": "Foo name"
            },
            {
                "column_id": 15,
                "type": "text",
                "varname": "foo_bar",
                "label": "Foo Bar",
                "value": "beers beers beers",
                "is_core": "yes",
                "orig_label": "Foo Bar"
            }

Unfortunately, the Data is structured in such a way that if in the front end there is a blank value, then the API does not pass an Object. So, you may get 10 objects in the JSON, you may get 4. This means I cannot be lazy and select the value by the data[1].value.
I need to dynamically search for the varname, then in that object select the value.
So far, I have something like this:
@substring(coalesce(activity().outputs?.body?.data, ''),'foo_id').value
What I want to return in the above is '1234' if that object exists, or if it does not exist - just pass a ''
But I am not getting the output I expect. Once I have the dynamic content string sussed, I will be able to do the rest of them - but I am stuck on this one aspect.
Hopefully someone can help with the dynamic content query string.


Create a new string variable to store the value of required output. Give the default value for that string as empty string.

You can add the for each activity next to web activity that pulls the data from legacy API. In items of for-each setting, give the dynamic expression as @activity().outputs?.body?.data.

Inside for-each activity, take an if activity and give the dynamic condition for if activity as @equals(item().varname,'foo2_id').




Inside true section of if activity, add a set variable activity to set the value for the variable. Give the expression for that variable as @item().value.



Thank you very much, I needed to do a bit of tweaking due to factors with the actual live dataset and other issues - but once tweaked - it worked.

Great to Know, this worked
